# Поиск данных между двумя датами

Tags: java, spring

Есть метод, который ищет данные между двумя датами. Но не включительно. Т.е. данные записанные в эти дни он не учитывает. Как это исправить?

```
default List<Orders> findByOrdersDate(List<Orders> ordersWorkerList, Date date1, Date date2){

        List<Orders> newOrdersList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Orders value: ordersWorkerList){
            if (value.getDate().after(date1) && value.getDate().before(date2)){
                newOrdersList.add(value);
            }
        }
        return newOrdersList;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (Orders value: ordersWorkerList) {
 if (!value.getDate().before(date1) && !value.getDate().after(date2)) {
    newOrdersList.add(value);
  }
}
```

Если выбирать даты, которые **не раньше** начальной и **не позже** конечной, то   даты, совпадающие с `date1` и `date2` тоже будут учитываться

Answer (score 1):

Правильнее ответ Mairenn. Но ещё можно создать свои функции. *С композицией и предикатами!™*

```
BiPredicate<Date, Date> equals = Date::equals;
BiPredicate<Date, Date> equalsOrAfter = equals.or(Date::after);
BiPredicate<Date, Date> equalsOrBefore = equals.or(Date::before);

...

Date date = value.getDate();
if (equalsOrAfter.test(date, date1) && equalsOrBefore.test(date, date2)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<Order> findByOrdersDate(List<Order> ordersWorkerList, Date beg, Date end) {
    Predicate<Order> geBeg = o -> !o.getDate().before(beg);
    Predicate<Order> leEnd = o -> !o.getDate().after(end);
    return ordersWorkerList.stream()
            .filter(geBeg)
            .filter(leEnd)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Orders value: ordersWorkerList){
    if (value.getDate() >= date1 && value.getDate() <= date2){
        newOrdersList.add(value);
    }
}
```

Если date1 - это "дата с" date2 - "дата по".

Comment: С какой версии жаба сравнивает даты с помощью математических знаков?
Или может забыли добавить например `getTime()`так: `value.getDate().getTime() >= date1.getTime()`? Или что-то с `compareTo()`: `value.getDate().compareTo(date1) >= 0`